# How to sort an array of structs in C?

Tags: c, sorting

I have got an array of the following structs:

```
typedef struct _my_data_ 
{
  unsigned int id;
  double latitude;
  double longitude;
  unsigned int content_len;
  char* name_dyn;
  char* descr_dyn;
} mydata;
```

and I would like to sort it ascending by the **ID** field. I read it is possible to sort arrays using the `qsort` function but I am not sure how to correctly use it when sorting structs.

Comment: Have you written a function that can tell you which of two given structs has a larger or smaller `id` field?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need a structure comparator function that matches the prototype of the function expected by `qsort()`, viz:

```
int md_comparator(const void *v1, const void *v2)
{
    const mydata *p1 = (mydata *)v1;
    const mydata *p2 = (mydata *)v2;
    if (p1->id < p2->id)
        return -1;
    else if (p1->id > p2->id)
        return +1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

If you ever get to a more complex sort criterion, this is still a good basis because you can add secondary criteria using the same skeleton:

```
int md_comparator(const void *v1, const void *v2)
{
    const mydata *p1 = (mydata *)v1;
    const mydata *p2 = (mydata *)v2;
    if (p1->latitude < p2->latitude)
        return -1;
    else if (p1->latitude > p2->latitude)
        return +1;
    else if (p1->longitude < p2->longitude)
        return -1;
    else if (p1->longitude > p2->longitude)
        return +1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Clearly, this repeats for as many criteria as you need.  If you need to call a function (`strcmp()`?) to compare values, call it once but assign the return to a local variable and use that twice:

```
int md_comparator(const void *v1, const void *v2)
{
    const mydata *p1 = (mydata *)v1;
    const mydata *p2 = (mydata *)v2;
    int rc;
    if (p1->latitude < p2->latitude)
        return -1;
    else if (p1->latitude > p2->latitude)
        return +1;
    else if (p1->longitude < p2->longitude)
        return -1;
    else if (p1->longitude > p2->longitude)
        return +1;
    else if ((rc = strcmp(p1->name_dyn, p2->name_dyn)) < 0)
        return -1;
    else if (rc > 0)
        return +1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Also, this template works when data members are unsigned integers, and it avoids overflow problems when comparing signed integers.  Note that the short cut you might sometimes see, namely variations on:

```
int md_comparator(const void *v1, const void *v2)   /* BAD */
{                                                   /* BAD */
    const mydata *p1 = (mydata *)v1;                /* BAD */
    const mydata *p2 = (mydata *)v2;                /* BAD */
    return(p1->id - p2->id);                        /* BAD */
}                                                   /* BAD */
```

is bad if `id` is unsigned (the difference of two unsigned integers is never negative), and subject to overflow if the integers are signed and of large magnitude and opposite signs.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, I'm going to try this code right now.

Comment: Meditations on 'if `id` is unsigned': since the return is `int`, the `unsigned` value will be converted to `int`, so it could become negative.  However, if `id` was `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long`, and `sizeof(long) > sizeof(int)` then you'd be vulnerable to some very odd behaviour.  The observation that the explicit return ±1 mechanism always works is still accurate; the sweeping "subtraction doesn't work if the comparison of two unsigned quantities" is not strictly accurate.