# Sort down a c struct

Tags: c++, c, struct

How can i sort down this struct only with the int ?

```
   struct buch {         
   string buchtitel;
   int preis;
   } buch;
```

Comment: You need more explaination about your issue, sorting a lonely struct is not something that makes sense. Maybe you forgot avout a vector or a list of `buch` to be sorted ?

Comment: Why have you created an instance of buch also called buch?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort an array of structs in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8721189/how-to-sort-an-array-of-structs-in-c)

Comment: Yet again: are you asking about C or C++? They are different languages, with different libraries offering different ways to sort things.

Comment: I think by the user accepting my answer, it is obvious that I correctly determined what they were asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is C++11 you can use a lambda function.

```
std::sort
  ( 
     beginIter, endIter, 
     []( buch const& lhs, buch const& rhs ){ return lhs.preis < rhs.preis; } 
  );
```

where `beginIter` and `endIter` define random-access iterators to the items you wish to sort, `endIter` being one past the end of the range.