# sort/search in stack

Tags: c, stack

I have created a stack system in C

It takes the First Name, Last name, and an employee number and the program runs fine.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define MAX 20

struct system
{
char first_name[15];
char surname[15];
}employee[20], temp;

int stack[MAX],front=-1,top=-1;
int i;
void push_element();
void pop_element();
void display_stack();
void display_first();

int main()
{
  int option;
  printf("STACK PROGRAM");
  do
  {
   printf("\n\n 1.Push an element");
   printf("\n 2.Pop an element");
   printf("\n 3.Display stack");
   printf("\n 4.Display first");
   printf("\n 5.Display last");
   printf("\n 6.Exit");
   printf("\n Enter your choice: ");
   scanf("%d",&option);
   switch(option)
    {
      case 1: push_element();
          break;
      case 2: pop_element();
         break;
      case 3: display_stack();
         break;
      case 4: display_first();
        break;
      case 5: display_last();
        break;
      case 6: return 0;
   }

  }while(option!=6);
}

void push_element() 
{
  printf("\n Enter the first name: ");
  scanf("%s",employee[i].first_name);

  printf("\n Enter the Last name: ");
  scanf("%s",employee[i].surname);

  int num;
  printf("\n Enter the employee number: ");
  scanf("%d",&num);
    i++;
  if(front==0 && top==MAX-1)
    printf("\n You have entered more than 20. Please delete a current input to make room. ");
  else if(front==-1&&top==-1)
  {
      front=top=0;
      stack[top]=num;

  }
  else if(top==MAX-1 && front!=0)
  {
    top=0;
    stack[top]=num;
  }
  else
  {
      top++;
      stack[top]=num;
  }
}

void pop_element()
{
top--;
    return top;
}

void display_stack()
{
    int i;
    if(front==-1)
      printf("\n No Employees to display");
    else
    {
       printf("\n List of employees:\n\n ");
       printf("  Employee number    First Name    Surname\n\n");
      for(i=front;i<=top;i++)
      {
          printf("   %d \t\t     %s  \t   %s\n", stack[i], employee[i].first_name, employee[i].surname);
      }
    }
}

void display_first()
{
    int i;
    if(front==-1)
      printf("\n No Employees to display");
    else
    {
      printf("\n The first Employee in the stack is:\n\n ");
      printf("  Employee number    First Name    Surname\n\n");
      for(i=front;i<=top;i++)
        break;
      {
          printf("   %d \t\t     %s  \t   %s\n", stack[i], employee[i].first_name, employee[i].surname);
      }
    }
}

void display_last()
{
    int i;
    if(front==-1)
      printf("\n No Employees to display");
    else
    {
      printf("\n The last Employee in the stack is:\n \n");
      printf("  Employee number    First Name    Surname\n\n");
      for(i=top;i<=front;i++)
        break;
      {
          printf("   %d \t\t     %s  \t   %s\n", stack[i], employee[i].first_name, employee[i].surname);
      }
    }
}
```

I for the life of me cannot figure out how to sort the stack. I have tried other pieces of code and many different things, but none of them have came close to finding it
But I am wanting to sort it by **alphabetical** order. So not by entry time or Employee number, but by the First initial of the Surname

A search function is also required for this, and to be done by Employee number.

I have looked online, and the use of sorting and searching in a stack isn't a common thing, but I required to have it.

I am not good at C and I am fairly new to it. Any tips or things that may help me greatly would be appreciated. Also I apologies for any formatting errors, I'm fairly new to programming altogether and using software.

Comment: Use quick sort.  qsort() in stdlib.h  (I think).

Comment: I think the OP is puzzled by how to sort on a stack. There's no random access! The "cheating" solution may be to copy everything to an array and sort that ... or to a sorted data structure (std::set) right away! (And then back onto the stack.)

Comment: @PeterSchneider: The stack is implemented as an array; sorting the array will sort the stack.  (Using `std::set` won't help in a C program — it becomes a C++ program at that point.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you are right, and you are right! Geez ;-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data structure doesn't directly record an employee number.  You have the array `stack` which records the employee number, and the array `employee` which records names.  You need to preserve the relationship *`stack[i]` contains the employee number for `employee[i]`* which means any sorting of the existing data structure has to sort two arrays in parallel.  While it *can* be done, it is not the best way to fix the problems (and it is harder than it need be, and will require a custom sort function).

You should upgrade the data structure to include the employee number:

```
struct employee
{
    int  number;
    char first_name[15];
    char surname[15];
} employee[20];
```

Note that I've retagged the structure as `struct employee` (instead of `struct system`) since it seems more relevant to the content of the structure.

You can then use the `qsort()` function from the standard C library (declared in `<stdlib.h>`) and the techniques documented in the proposed duplicate ([How to sort an array of structs in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8721189/how-to-sort-an-array-of-structs-in-c)) to sort the data straight-forwardly.  It is also easier to write your searching code.

You can also clean up the display code; you can have a single function that is passed an employee structure (or pointer to one). It will contain a single `printf()` statement that formats the data correctly.  This saves you writing the same elaborate `printf()` code 3 times, making it easier to fix the formatting if (when) you need to do so.  You can also avoid using tabs in the output (generally a good idea), leading to:

```
void print_employee(const struct employee *emp)
{
    printf("%8d   %-15s  %-15s\n", emp->number, emp->first_name, emp->surname);
}
```

This will produce well aligned output unless your employee number grows to more than 8 digits (in which case, change the 8 to 10 or whatever).  You can also generalize one step further if you wish, passing a `FILE *fp` argument to the function, and using `fprintf(fp, "…", …)` instead of `printf()`.

You call the function:

```
print_employee(&employee[i]);
```

You might also consider a function to print the headings since you have that function call 3 times.  Alternatively, you might just have a constant string at file scope that contains the correct headings which you use in 3 places.  You could do that with the `print_employee()` function too; have a constant string at file scope that is the format you use.

Also, in your `display_first()` and `display_last()` functions, the loops are curious.  You've written:

```
  for(i=front;i<=top;i++)
    break;
  {
      printf("   %d \t\t     %s  \t   %s\n", stack[i], employee[i].first_name, employee[i].surname);
  }
```

You should realize (on review) that this is equivalent to:

```
i = front;
printf("   %d \t\t     %s  \t   %s\n", stack[i], employee[i].first_name, employee[i].surname);
```

(If `front` is larger than `top`, then `i = front` is the only part of the loop executed; otherwise, the `break` is executed; either way, after the loop, `i == front`.)