# Casting types of function while sending it as an argument to 'qsort'

Tags: c, sorting

```
typedef void* ListElement;
typedef int(*CompareListElements)(ListElement, ListElement);

ListResult listSort(List list, CompareListElements compareElement) {
    .
    .
    .
    qsort(arr, size, sizeof(*arr), compareElement);
    .
    .
    .
}
```

The first two lines are to clarify what is the `CompareListElements.`
When I send `compareElement` as an argument to the library function 'qsort' I receive these warning messages:

```
passing argument 4 of 'qsort' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: the arguments of the comparator passed to `qsort` are supposed to be `const`. Your's are not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Avoid undefined behaviour

Rewrite the comparator so it matches what `qsort()` expects:

```
typedef int (*CompareListElements)(const void *, const void *);
```

And inside the comparator, do the conversion to the correct type:

```
int compare_elements(const void *v1, const void *v2)
{
    const RealType *p1 = v1;
    const RealType *p2 = v2;
    …do comparison…
    return …;
}
```

This way, you don't cast the function pointer at all.  The `RealType` is whatever is the type hidden behind the (poorly chosen):

```
typedef void *ListElement;
```

The real type is not `void`; it is probably some structure type.  Note that using `void *` as the list element type loses almost all the type safety that's available with C (which is arguably little enough to begin with).  You'd do better with:

```
typedef struct Element ListElement;
```

or something like that, and passing pointers to `ListElement` around.  (See also [Is it a good idea to `typedef` pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers/750208#750208).  You may also find [How to sort an array of structs in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8721189/how-to-sort-an-array-of-structs-in-c/8721241#8721241) helpful, and there are undoubtedly other related questions that will help.).

#### Why does the cast lead to undefined behaviour?

Note that casting the function pointer leads to undefined behaviour according to the C standard:

> **C11 [§6.3 Conversions — §6.3.2.3 Pointers ¶8](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3)**
>
> A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a function of another type and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer. If a converted pointer is used to call a function whose type is not compatible with the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.

So, while it is permissible to cast a function pointer that doesn't match what `qsort()` expects, the problem is that `qsort()` will invoke it as the converted type, and that is not generally [compatible](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.7) with the function's type, so the behaviour is undefined — notwithstanding examples to the contrary published by demigods in the Unix pantheon.

Often, you will get away with it, but the standard says you may not always get away with it.  Since the fix is fairly simple, use it; avoid undefined behaviour.