# After each printed line there are 2 blank lines

Tags: c, file, printf

I am trying to create a function which with read from a file some grades with the student names and print the grades in decreasing order. This is the function:

```
char studenteUN[50];
int punti;
int maxP = MAX_LNG;
int max = -1000;
int min = MAX_LNG;

FILE *ftemp = f;
while(fscanf(ftemp, "%s", studenteUN) != EOF){
  fscanf(ftemp, "%d", &punti);
  if(punti < min)
    min = punti;
}

while (maxP != min) {
  max = -1000;
  ftemp = muovi(f);
  while(fscanf(ftemp, "%s", studenteUN) != EOF){
    fscanf(ftemp, "%d", &punti);
    if(punti > max && punti < maxP)
      max = punti;
  }
  maxP = max;
  ftemp = muovi(f);
  while(fscanf(ftemp, "%s", studenteUN) != EOF){
    fscanf(ftemp, "%d", &punti);
    if(punti == max)
      printf("%s %d\n", studenteUN, punti);
  }
}
```

Te output is the following:

```
asdas 8


asdas 7


asdsa 6


andrea 5


asd 4


asd 1
asdsad 1


asdas 0
asd 0
```

I can not figure it out why this happens.
The file I read from is the following:

```
2
1- askd a
   1- asd
   2- asd as
   3- asd as d
   4- asdas
   5- Non lo so.
1
2- asdsad asd as d
   1- asd a
   2- asd
   3- asd
   4- as df
   5- Non lo so.
2
andrea 5
asdsa 6
asdas 7
asd 1
asdas 0
asd 0
asdsad 1
asdas 8
asd 4
```

The muovi function:

```
FILE *muovi(FILE *f){
 fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
 char resultato[MAX_LNG];
 int nD;
 fscanf(f, "%d", &nD);
 printf("\n");
 for(int i = 0; i <= nD*7;i++)
  fgets(resultato, MAX_LNG, f);
 return f;
}
```

Comment: What is `muovi(f)`? Is it the same as `fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET)`?

Comment: In the file this lines are in the second middle, so I use this method to move the pointer to the file to the neccesary place.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], including an example of the input file you read from.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I added the file i read from

Comment: I put your code in a `main()` function and I couldn't reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Even if the input file is double-spaced, `fscanf` using `%d` and `%s` should filter that out.

Comment: Are you writing the file in text mode or binary mode? If text mode, the issue may just be how you are viewing the contents of the file.

Comment: It's because of `printf("\n");` in `muovi()`

Comment: BTW, this is a horrible way to do this, rereading the file for every place. Read everything into an array of structures, sort the array, and then print the array.

Comment: @Barmar first time I am trying to do this so still learning. Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8721189/how-to-sort-an-array-of-structs-in-c

Comment: @Barmar Would it be a good idea if I used a structure list with pointers?

Comment: @EntiolLiko you can also use a big enough array of structs to get your logic to work, and not deal with dynamic allocation

Comment: There are several problems here. The main problem is that you trying to all things in one step - that's a bad design. Break the task into minor tasks that you can do one by one. That is: 1) Read the file into an array 2) Sort the array 3) Print the array

Comment: @EntiolLiko That's probably how a pro would do it, so it just sorts pointers instead of copying whole structures. But it's not really that important at tihs stage of learning.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a demo sample:
it reads input of the form 'name grade':

```c
student1 1
student2 7
student3 -4
student4 11
student5 1111
student6 -11111
```

And outputs:

```c
student5 1111
student4 11
student2 7
student1 1
student3 -4
student6 -11111
```

Here is the code behind, perhaps you can make an idea

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct studs {
    int grade;
    char name[50];
};

int md_comparator(const void *v1, const void *v2)
{
    const struct studs *p1 = (struct studs *)v1;
    const struct studs *p2 = (struct studs *)v2;
    
    if (p1->grade < p2->grade)
        return 1;
    else if (p1->grade > p2->grade)
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
}


int main()
{
    struct studs students[1000];
    struct studs temp;
    
    //read all students into students[] array
    int idx = 0;
    for (; fscanf(stdin, "%s %d", temp.name, &temp.grade) == 2; students[idx++] = temp)
        ;
    
    //sort descending, with the help of qsort and md_comparator function above
    qsort(students, idx, sizeof(students[0]), md_comparator);
    
    //print
    for (int i = 0; i < idx; i++)
        printf("%s %d\n", students[i].name, students[i].grade);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you read each line with `fgets()` into a buffer and then use `sscanf` to parse the buffer checking that the return is 2 -- you can read the entire file only picking out the student data.

Answer (score 0):

When reading lines of data from a file, you want to use a *line-oriented* input function such as `fgets()` or POSIX `getline()`. This ensures a complete line of input is consumed during each read. Otherwise when looking for a pattern, like a string followed by an integer, partial reads will likely lead to false-matches depending on what parts of the line are left in the input-buffer unread.

After reading each line into a buffer, you can simply parse the needed information from each line using `sscanf()` instead of your attempt to both read and parse with `fscanf()`.

Putting that together, it is no problem at all to read and isolate only the student name and number from the file, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NAMC 50         /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXC 1024

typedef struct {        /* struct for student name and number */
    char name[NAMC];
    int no;
} student;

int cmpstd (const void *a, const void *b)   /* qsort descending by student.no */
{
    const student *pa = a, *pb = b;
    
    return (pa->no < pb->no) - (pa->no > pb->no);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    student std[NAMC];      /* array of student */
    char buf[MAXC];         /* buffer to hold line */
    int n = 0;              /* student counter */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;
    
    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }
    
    while (n < NAMC && fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) { /* limit to array sz, read line */
        student tmp;        /* temporary struct for student */
        /* parse name and number from line, validating return */
        if (sscanf (buf, "%s %d", tmp.name, &tmp.no) == 2)
            std[n++] = tmp; /* add to array */
    }
    
    if (fp != stdin)   /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);
    
    qsort (std, n, sizeof *std, cmpstd);    /* sort by student.no descending */
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)             /* output results */
        printf ("%-10s %d\n", std[i].name, std[i].no);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your input file in `dat/prefixedstd.txt` you would receive the following:

```
$ ./bin/read_prefixstd dat/prefixedstd.txt
asdas      8
asdas      7
asdsa      6
andrea     5
asd        4
asd        1
asdsad     1
asdas      0
asd        0
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a question. I am trying to write a function which will add a student to the file (so username, password,status(int 1 or 0)). Which would be a better solution: 1- Get all the data from the file and put it into a list, modify the list and in the end write a funtion to write all the changes to the file or 2-Write to the file directy using only 1 function? Thanks